# estatus de orden de compra

Tags: sql

estoy creando una consulta en SQL server donde quiero poner una estatus usando un case a las ordenes de compra que tengo en el sistema.

Si la fecha de recibo ya paso entonces el estado tendría que decir vencido, pero si la fecha esta por vencer dentro de la próxima semana tiene que decir que ya se venció, si la orden aun no llega a la semana para vencer que no salga en la consulta.

Actualmente tengo algo así:

```
SELECT A1.PO_No,A1.Send_Supplier_Notification,A1.Currency_Code,A2.Supplier_Code,A3.PO_Status,A1.Due_Date,
       CASE  WHEN GETDATE() >= A1.Due_Date THEN 'VENCIDO'
             WHEN GETDATE() <= DATEADD(D,-5, A1.Due_Date) THEN 'POR VENCER'
       END as ESTADO
       FROM Purchasing_v_PO A1
       INNER JOIN Common_v_Supplier_e A2 ON A1.Supplier_No = A2.Supplier_No
       INNER JOIN Purchasing_v_PO_Status_e A3 ON A1.PO_Status_Key = A3.PO_Status_Key
       WHERE A1.PO_Status_Key = 228 
       ORDER BY A1.PO_No
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usadas el getdate() la informacion que trae el mismo es la fecha y la hora Ej. 2020-03-03 16:24:17.540, si A1.Due_Date no es datetime tendrás problemas para comparar las fechas te aconsejaria que realizaras un convert y llevar la fecha al mismo formato

Ejemplo.

```
SELECT A1.PO_No,A1.Send_Supplier_Notification,A1.Currency_Code,A2.Supplier_Code,A3.PO_Status,A1.Due_Date,

CASE  WHEN convert (varchar, GETDATE(),112) >= convert (varchar, A1.Due_Date,112) THEN 'VENCIDO'
           else
            THEN 'POR VENCER'
END as ESTADO

FROM Purchasing_v_PO A1
INNER JOIN Common_v_Supplier_e A2 ON A1.Supplier_No = A2.Supplier_No
INNER JOIN Purchasing_v_PO_Status_e A3 ON A1.PO_Status_Key = A3.PO_Status_Key
WHERE A1.PO_Status_Key = 228 
ORDER BY A1.PO_No
```

otra cosa mas si solo tienes dos status vencido y por vencer lo puedes hacerlo como muestro en el ejemplo.